# Automatic scroll jqgrid into the current day column and blink effect of the cell that has a stored data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I am loading a jqgrid with approximately 38 columns of data. The first 6 column was frozen and other column was unfrozen (It is a date & month depends on the combo box. please see the sample image [here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8XcwJpZImDU/UBCWeEZGQwI/AAAAAAAAAIY/2hvuGulgw8Y/s1543/untitled.JPG) ).   When the data is finished loading the jqgrid, I would like to automatically scroll the jqgrid to a specific column in the current day of the month next to the last column of the columns that was frozen. The scroll will depend on the current day (ex: if today is July 26,2012 it would automatically scroll to that specififc day and so on).

And the other is when that day has received data that cell will blink into red and green (those cell that has a data or value will blink into two colors), something like that.

Is anyone has an idea how to do this?
Thanks! . Please see [here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8XcwJpZImDU/UBCWeEZGQwI/AAAAAAAAAIY/2hvuGulgw8Y/s1543/untitled.JPG) the sample image of the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function to scroll to current Date column

```
function scrollToCurrentDate(currentDate,jqGrid){
    var width =0 ;
    var frozenWidth = 0;
    for(var i =0,col;col=jqGrid[0].p.colModel[i];i++){
        width += $("#"+jqGrid[0].id+"_"+col.name)[0].offsetWidth;
        if(col.name.indexOf('Qty')==0){
            var day = col.name.replace('Qty','');
            var date = $("#CurrentYear").val()+'-'+$("#CurrentMonth").val()+'-'+(parseInt(day)<10?"0"+day:day);

            if(currentDate == date){  
                var columnWidth = $("#"+jqGrid[0].id+"_"+col.name)[0].offsetWidth;
                $(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv").scrollLeft((width-columnWidth)-frozenWidth);
                $(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").scrollLeft((width-columnWidth)-frozenWidth);
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
          frozenWidth += $("#"+jqGrid[0].id+"_"+col.name)[0].offsetWidth;    
        }
    }
}
```

And then I call this function in gridComplete:

```
scrollToCurrentDate(currentDate,$("#table"));
```

And in the Blink effect here's the code.

```
var blinkStatus=false;
var blink = function(){
        //$(".blinker").toggle();
        $(".txtBlinker").css("background-color", blinkStatus?"#CFC":"#FF4F4F");
        blinkStatus=!blinkStatus;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {

        setInterval(blink, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, i want you to write code for it yourself, i can give you some idea on this.

implement the LoadComplete function of jqgrid and check which column has current date and on that column call focus method of jquery.

it would be something like this

var Id=//id of the row which has a column with current date.

get that column by using jquery selectors, you know with tr and td,they will have some id, check developer tools for this and then call focus method of jquery on that column

or if u want that column to have a blinking effect,

check this

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/blink,

let me know if have further problems.

P.S- mark it as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Piyush Sardana.